# How to count rows in a logical vector

Tags: r

I have a data frame called source that looks something like this

```
185  2002-07-04      NA      NA 20
186  2002-07-05      NA      NA 20
187  2002-07-06      NA      NA 20
188  2002-07-07  14.400   0.243 20
189  2002-07-08      NA      NA 20
190  2002-07-09      NA      NA 20
191  2002-07-10      NA      NA 20
192  2002-07-11      NA      NA 20
193  2002-07-12      NA      NA 20
194  2002-07-13   4.550   0.296 20
195  2002-07-14      NA      NA 20
196  2002-07-15      NA      NA 20
197  2002-07-16      NA      NA 20
198  2002-07-17      NA      NA 20
199  2002-07-18      NA      NA 20
200  2002-07-19      NA   0.237 20
```

and when I try

```
> nrow(complete.cases(source))
```

I only get NULL

can someone explain why this is the case and how can I count how many rows there are without NA or NaN values?

Comment: You could also use `nrow(na.exclude(source))` (IMHO you should not name your data source as it's a common used base R function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead use `sum`. Though the safest option would be `NROW` (because it can handle both data.frams and vectors)

```
sum(complete.cases(source))
#[1] 2
```

Or alternatively if you insist on using `nrow`

```
nrow(source[complete.cases(source), ])
#[1] 2
```

Explanation: `complete.cases` returns a logical vector indicating which cases (in your case rows) are complete.

---

### Sample data

```
source <- read.table(text = 
    "185  2002-07-04      NA      NA 20
186  2002-07-05      NA      NA 20
187  2002-07-06      NA      NA 20
188  2002-07-07  14.400   0.243 20
189  2002-07-08      NA      NA 20
190  2002-07-09      NA      NA 20
191  2002-07-10      NA      NA 20
192  2002-07-11      NA      NA 20
193  2002-07-12      NA      NA 20
194  2002-07-13   4.550   0.296 20
195  2002-07-14      NA      NA 20
196  2002-07-15      NA      NA 20
197  2002-07-16      NA      NA 20
198  2002-07-17      NA      NA 20
199  2002-07-18      NA      NA 20
200  2002-07-19      NA   0.237 20")
```

Answer (score 0):

`complete.cases` returns a logical vector that indicates the rows which are complete. As a vector doesn't have a row attribute, you cannot use `nrow` here, but as suggested by others `sum`. With `sum` the `TRUE` and `FALSE` are transformed to `1` and `0` internally, so using `sum` counts the `TRUE` values of your vector.

```
sum(complete.cases(source))
# [1] 2
```

If you however are more interested in the `data.frame`, which is left after you exclude all non-complete rows, you can use `na.exclude`. This returns a `data.frame` and you can use `nrow`.

```
nrow(na.exclude(source))
# [1] 2

na.exclude(source)
#             V2    V3    V4 V5
# 188 2002-07-07 14.40 0.243 20
# 194 2002-07-13  4.55 0.296 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even try:

```
source[rowSums(is.na(source))==0,]
#     V1         V2    V3    V4 V5
# 4  188 2002-07-07 14.40 0.243 20
# 10 194 2002-07-13  4.55 0.296 20

nrow(source[rowSums(is.na(source))==0,])
#[1] 2
```